# Choosing a random item from one of two lists, based on a random item from a third

Tags: python, list, random, reference

I am trying to select a random city of a random country, using the following code:

```
COUNTRIES= ["NL", "NO"]

NL = [
    "Assen", "Almere", "Leeuwarden", "Nijmegen", "Groningen", 
    "Maastricht", "Eindhoven", "Amsterdam", "Enschede", "Utrecht", 
    "Middelburg", "Rotterdam"
]

NO = [
    "Fredrikstad", "Baerum", "Oslo", "Ringsaker", "Gjovik", 
    "Drammen", "Sandefjord", "Skien", "Arendal", "Kristiansand", 
    "Stavanger", "Bergen", "Forde", "Alesund", "Trondheim", 
    "Stjordal", "Bodo", "Tromso", "Alta"
]

CHOSEN_CITY = random.choice(random.choice(COUNTRIES))

print CHOSEN_CITY
```

However, this only ever gives me one of `'L'`, `'O'` or `N`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *but it doesn't work* Elaborate as to why

Comment: Presumably you're getting either `'N'`, `'L'` or `'O'` because `COUNTRIES` **contains two strings**, not the lists you actually want to choose from.

Comment: Please see the update. It returns only N for instance, what should I do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're choosing a random country and then choosing a random letter from each of those strings. That's not how Python works.

A better setup would be to store your data in a dictionary as below. You can then choose a random country (by choosing a random key in the dict). You would then use that random key to choose a random city.

```
import random

data = {
    'NL': ["Assen", "Almere", "Leeuwarden", "Nijmegen", "Groningen", "Maastricht", 
           "Eindhoven", "Amsterdam", "Enschede", "Utrecht", "Middelburg", "Rotterdam"],
    'NO': ["Fredrikstad", "Baerum", "Oslo", "Ringsaker", "Gjovik", "Drammen",
           "Sandefjord", "Skien", "Arendal", "Kristiansand", "Stavanger", "Bergen", 
           "Forde", "Alesund", "Trondheim", "Stjordal", "Bodo", "Tromso", "Alta"]
}

random_country = random.choice(list(data.keys()))
random_city = random.choice(data[random_country])

print(random_country, random_city)
# NO Drammen
```

Comment: This is a little more complex but much easier to make dynamic. +1

Comment: @TotempaaltJ I rejected your edit btw because it would break it for Python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object which is not indexable and so `random.choice` doesn't work on it. I realise that OP is using Python 2, but someone in the future may read it for 3 :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
random.choice(NL + NO)
```

Comment: +1 This is by far the shortest way, but TotempaaltJ's way, in my opinion, is a littler easier to manage.

Comment: It really depends on your particular scenario. My way would probably make more sense if you have several possible combinations of countries. If everything depends on (user) input, I'd say Ffisegydd's method makes most sense (no set variable names). If there's only ever a single combination, this is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how Python works! A string inside one list is not a reference to another variable, even if they share the same name.

```
NL = ["Assen", "Almere", "Leeuwarden"]  # truncated for clarity
NO = ["Fredrikstad", "Baerum", "Oslo"]

countries = [NL, NO]  # refer to variables, not just strings
chosen_city = random.choice(random.choice(countries))

print(chosen_city)
```

Should work. Simply choosing from two appended lists is more clear, but might not work in your particular scenario.